# Service Area or Catchment Area in R

Tags: arcmap, r, open-source-routing-machine, isochrone

I'm trying to find an R package to duplicate a specific bit of functionality of the ESRI network analyst: What ArcMap refers to as 'Service Areas'. Related terms include

- catchment areas
- isochrones
- 'reachability' (walkalytics package)
- network buffers

What I want **looks** like an isochrone, but rather than measuring the amount of distance covered in a specified unit of time, I want a polygon representing the bounds of all points within 1.25 miles over the street network.

- Nothing in the open streetmap routing machine (osrm package) meets my
  needs.
- Walkalytics isochrone would give me what i need, **if** I knew what
  the walking speed was.

Could someone either point me to a package with this functionality, or tell me what the Walkalytics default speed is?

I'd really like to be able to do this in R, rather than having to go back into ArcMap everytime I need to determine the network distance reachable from a given metro station.

Comment: OSRM (the engine under the osrm package) can return distance iso-lines. Here's the 1km walking distance from my local castle: https://maps.openrouteservice.org/reach?n1=54.048656&n2=-2.804217&n3=14&a=54.049774,-2.805137&b=2&i=1&j1=1&j2=1&k1=en-US&k2=km (assuming the URL works). Is that what you want? Does the R package not wrap that?

Comment: The R package does not appear to wrap that functionality: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osrm/osrm.pdf

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the walking distance and walking time are simply linearly related by a single walking speed. Infer that (or ask OSRM what speed they use) and you should be able to use isochrones.

Comment: Indeed! But without a walking rate, I can't convert between the two. As far as I can tell, OSRM only provides the default 'drivetime' profile without creating an instance of my own, something I fear is beyond my skills.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an R package that does this in one simple step but some packages that may help are:

[dodgr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dodgr/index.html) Which can do routing over route networks within R

[opentripplanner](https://github.com/ITSLeeds/opentripplanner) Can interface with a local or remote version of the Open Trip Planner that can make [isochrones](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Intermediate-Tutorial)

[stplanr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stplanr/index.html) Which can interface with several different services such as [graphhopper](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/isochrone/)

Comment: What I want is what Spacedman (above) refers to as distance-based iso-lines. Effectively, I want a polygon whose vertices are at maximum distances from a central point, given a certain distance.

Comment: The perhaps you could use `dodgr` to get the points a given distance from a point an then use `sf::st_convex_hull()` on those points

Comment: A very interesting idea. I just learned about dodgr today, actually. I've seen the convex hull suggested elsewhere, but without something like dodgr, it didn't seem feasible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718839/in-r-how-do-i-run-st-convex-hull-function-on-point-sf-object/51719497

Comment: Any idea how to use dodgr to estimate a distances along all routes?

Answer (score 0):

The Walkalytics package can be used for this purpose. I contacted  its developer (Stephan Heuel) on Twitter (@ping13), and he replied "The walking speed was modeled to be about 4.5 km/h."(Personal Communication, March 11 2019).